# how to install hadoop?can i use it simulate many computers?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

suppose i want to find connected components in a huge graph and the number of nodes is very large.i dont have many machines to do it.i want to just simulate a large network and the machines doing the computation using mapreduce. any direction?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

You can install Hadoop in a single computer and use it just for learning and developing.

Other option is to use Cloudera Virtual Machines (CDH4) (see http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/08/hadoop-on-your-pc-clouderas-cdh4-virtual-machine/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to simulate a *large* number of nodes, the only practical way of doing this is using a service like [Amazon's EMR](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/)